# Passing a C# callback function through Interop/pinvoke

Tags: c#, function, interop, callback, pinvoke

I am writing a C# application which uses Interop services to access functions in a native C++ DLL.  I am already using about 10 different functions which are working.

Now I am not sure how to handle passing a callback as a parameter so that the DLL can call my code.

Here is the function prototype of the DLL:

```
typedef void (WINAPI * lpfnFunc)(const char *arg1, const char *arg2)
```

And the function that allows me to pass the above type:

```
int WINAPI SetFunc(lpfnFunc f)
```

Here is my C# code for the delegate and function definitions:

```
public delegate void Func(string arg1, string arg2);

public static void MyFunc(string arg1, string arg2)
```

Here is my C# code for the SetFunc Interop function:

```
[DllImport("lib.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int SetFunc(Func lpfn);
```

And finally here is the code where I call the SetFunc function and pass it my callback:

```
SetFunc(new Func(MyFunc));
```

Unfortunately my function is not being called when it should be.  The return value of the SetFunc function is returning the error code for a Success, so either it's not calling my function or it's not working because my code is wrong.

Comment: The code is wrong, the delegate object is going to get garbage collected.  This normally produces a crash instead of 'just not working'.  Store the delegate in a variable so the garbage collector sees a reference to it.

Comment: I created a static reference.  It's still not getting called.  Must be a problem with the library.

Answer (score 18):

This works for me:

Calc.h (Calc.dll, C++):

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) double Calc(double x, double y, double __stdcall p(double, double));
```

Calc.cpp (Calc.dll, C++):

```
#include "calc.h"

__declspec(dllimport) double Calc(double x, double y, double __stdcall p(double, double))
{
    double s = p(x*x, y*y);
    return x * y + s;
}
```

Program.cs (Sample.exe, C#):

```
class Program
{
    delegate double MyCallback(double x, double y);
    [DllImport("Calc.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern double Calc(double x, double y, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]MyCallback func);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double z = Calc(1, 2, (x, y) => 45);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for me in C but the method declaration in both .h and .c should be dllexport. dllimport is not allowed

Answer (score 3):

Can you try changing the Func delegate to

```
    public delegate void Func([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string arg1, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string arg2);
```

And the SetFunc method to

```
[DllImport("lib", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
public static extern int SetFunc(Func lpfn);
```